# Swift, How can I reverse specific elements in arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an Array with different elements inside, it looks like this:

```
Vehicles = [ Auto(brand: "bmw", color: "red"),
             Auto(brand: "mazda", color: "red"),
             Auto(brand: "alfa romeo", color: "red"),
             Bike(brand: "suzuki", color: "blue"),
             Bike(brand: "yamaha", color: "black") ]
```

I need to reverse it based on "color" in this case, so the array would be like:

```
Vehicles = [ Auto(brand: "alfa romeo", color: "red"),
             Auto(brand: "mazda", color: "red"),
             Auto(brand: "bmw", color: "red"),
             Bike(brand: "suzuki", color: "blue"),
             Bike(brand: "yamaha", color: "black") ]
```

Elements with the same colors are following each others, like "sub groups", and I'd need to reverse each of these subgroups. ie: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i], if a,b,c are color 1, d,e,f color 2, and g,h,i of color 3, it's like [(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)], the order should be [(c,b,a), (f, e, d), (i,h,g)], and so [c,b,a,f,e,d,i,h,g]

Comment: reverse? Do you mean sort by color? `Vehicles.sort { $0.color > $1.color }`?

Comment: If yamaha is also blue, do you want to also reverse yamaha and suzuki too?

Comment: @Sulthan Sort I guess but I need to keep it in the same order but reversed, if x y z cars are red, the order should be z y x of those red cars

Comment: @Sweeper yes, also in that case

Comment: Therefore you want to probably sort them by both? In ascending order by brand and in descending order by color? `Vehicles.sort { $0.brand == $1.brand ? $0.color > $1.color : $0.brand < $1.brand }`

Comment: Do you mean, that in initial array: Cars with the same colors are following each others, like "sub groups", and you want to reverse each of these subgroups?
ie: [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i], if a,b,c are color 1, d,e,f color 2, and g,h,i of color 3, it's like [(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)], so you'd want [(c,b,a), (f, e, d), (i,h,g)], and so [c,b,a,f,e,d,i,h,g] ? Where subgroups with parentheses are "virtuals"?

Comment: @Sulthan I'd need to keep the color order, so if red comes first it should be first in the array, the brand just needs to be reversed, not sorted, so if in the original array the brands of green car are X Y Z the order should be Z Y X

Comment: @Larme yes, I'd need that

Comment: And the fact that it's a Bike or a Auto doesn't matter, or it does matter? You could add your explanation by editing your question with them. It's easier to read there than searching in all comments to understand your logic...

Comment: @Larme no, it doesn't matter

Comment: This task seems like you have a bad data architecture in the first place. If brand order is supposed to stay the same, then I assume they have some defined order and probably that order should be somewhere stored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in three steps:

1. Break your collection into subcollections based on color changes. Apple's [swift-algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms) package has an operator named [`chunked(by:)`](https://github.com/apple/swift-algorithms/blob/main/Guides/Chunked.md) that is perfect for this. [Read here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/adding_package_dependencies_to_your_app) about adding package dependencies to your app.
2. Reverse each subcollection. You can use the standard library [`reversed()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641355-reversed) method for this.
3. Concatenate the subcollections. You can use the standard library [`joined()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2431985-joined) method for this.

```swift
vehicles = vehicles
    .chunked { $0.color == $1.color }
    .map { $0.reversed() }
    .joined()
```

If you want more complex logic inside the `chunked` predicate, you need to use named arguments so you can declare its return type:

```swift
vehicles = vehicles
    .chunked { a, b -> Bool in
        switch (a.type, b.type) {
        case (.car, .car): return a.color == b.color
        case (.bike, .bike): return a.color == b.color
        default: return false
        }
    }
    .map { $0.reversed() }
    .joined()
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a switch case inside the chunked function? Because the vehicles array contains different kinds of datas

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: In `chunked()` closure, you have 2 parameters, which are 2 objects from `vehicles`. You compare them the way you want, but if you want them to be in the same `chunk` return `true`, if not, return `false`.  So do whatever comparison you want, either only color, type, other properties, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With model & input:

```
protocol Vehicle: CustomStringConvertible {
    var brand: String { get set }
    var color: String { get set }
}

extension Vehicle {
    var description: String {
        "Brand: \(brand) - color: \(color)"
    }
}
struct Bike: Vehicle {
    var brand: String
    var color: String
}
struct Auto: Vehicle {
    var brand: String
    var color: String
}

let vehicles: [Vehicle] = [ Auto(brand: "bmw", color: "red"),
                            Auto(brand: "mazda", color: "red"),
                            Auto(brand: "alfa romeo", color: "red"),
                            Bike(brand: "suzuki", color: "blue"),
                            Bike(brand: "suzuki2", color: "blue"),
                            Bike(brand: "suzuki3", color: "blue"),
                            Bike(brand: "yamaha", color: "black"),
                            Bike(brand: "yamaha2", color: "black")]
```

A possible solution, without needing Apple's extra Collection Packages as [mentionned by rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69886724/1801544)

```
// Here we create batches, ie subgroups of Vehicle with the same color using `reduce(into:_)`

let batched = vehicles.reduce(into: [[Vehicle]]()) { partialResult, aVehicle in
    //If there is already a batch, we check the last one, and inside that batch, we check the last Vehicle color
   // If it's the same color of the one currently checked (aVehicle), then we append it
    if var lastBatch = partialResult.last, let lastVehicle = lastBatch.last, lastVehicle.color == aVehicle.color {
        lastBatch.append(aVehicle)
        partialResult[partialResult.count - 1] = lastBatch
    } else {
        partialResult.append([aVehicle]) //We create a new batch
    }
}

print("batched: \(batched)")

// Here we reverse each batch
let reversedBatch = batched.map { aBatch -> [Vehicle] in
    return aBatch.reversed() //return can be omitted here
}
print("reversedBatch: \(reversedBatch)")

//We remove the subgroup, flattening the array
let reversed = reversedBatch.flatMap { $0 }
print("reversed: \(reversed)")
```

Now, that we got the main idea, we can do the first operation and the second one, in one go. Instead of appending, we put it as the beginning of the batch

```
let batchedAndReversed = vehicles.reduce(into: [[Vehicle]]()) { partialResult, aVehicle in
    if var lastBatch = partialResult.last, let lastVehicle = lastBatch.last, lastVehicle.color == aVehicle.color {
        lastBatch.insert(aVehicle, at: 0)
        partialResult[partialResult.count - 1] = lastBatch
    } else {
        partialResult.append([aVehicle]) //We create a new batch
    }
}
let reversed2 = batchedAndReversed.flatMap { $0 }
print("reversed2: \(reversed2)")
```